# How can I check the selected values of multiple RadioButtonLists?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a HTML `form` that has multiple `RadioButtonLists`.

```
<div>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="2"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
</div>
<div>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList2" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="3"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="4"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
</div>

<div>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList3" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="5" Text="5"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="6" Text="6"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
</div>

<div>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList4" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="7" Text="7"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="8" Text="8"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
</div>
```

How can I iterate through each `RadioButtonList` to select each value?

This is what I have got so far, am I on the right track or is there a better way to do this?

```
int value1= 0;
int value2= 0;

if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue == "1")
{
    value1++;
}
else if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue == "2")
{
    value2++;

}

if (RadioButtonList2.SelectedValue == "1")
{
    value1++;
}
else if (RadioButtonList2.SelectedValue == "2")
{
    value2++;

}
```

I have also tried this but cant seem to get it all correct

```
foreach(RadioButtonList rbl in ?????) 
{
    if (rbl.SelectedValue == "1")
    {
        value1++;
    }
    else if (rbl.SelectedValue == "2")
    {
        value2++;
    }
}
```

Any help or point in the right direction would be very helpful!

Thanks

Comment: You could start by making `value` an array, so you can use indexes...

Comment: Why not make a [Control Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435293/how-do-i-make-a-control-array-in-c-sharp-2010-net) and access them that way?  That would make your `foreach` loop look like this:  `foreach(RadioButtonList rbl in /Your array goes here/)`.

Comment: In your HTML, none of your ASP items have ID values. Those are required, and that is how your code knows how to access one versus another.

Comment: @jp2code You mean for the individual list items? No actually; the code doesn't need to access the list items themselves to know what the value of the radio button group is. List items are special in that regard; they don't even need runat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done similar things before (namely, manipulating different validator controls). Here's how I'd do it:

```
var radioButtons = new List<RadioButtonList>() 
{
    RadioButtonList1,
    RadioButtonList2,
    RadioButtonList3,
    RadioButtonList4,
};

foreach(RadioButtonList rbl in radioButtons) 
{
    if (rbl.SelectedValue == "1")
    {
        value1++;
    }
    else if (rbl.SelectedValue == "2")
    {
        value2++;
    }
}
```

You can define the list of `RadioButtonList` as a private field within your ASP.NET page or user control

Comment: I never thought about making a list of the lists! :P Worked perfectly thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you put all RadioButtonLists inside a DIV with *runat="server"* you can easily loop through only RadioButtonLists inside of that DIV. Here is a simple example that is triggered on Button1 click, you can put a debug point at the end of Button1 click event to see the value of value1 and value2.

**ASP.NET Code-Behind:**

```
<div id="myradiolist" runat="server">
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="2"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>

    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList2" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="3"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="4"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>

    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList3" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="5" Text="5"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="6" Text="6"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>

    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList4" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="7" Text="7"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="8" Text="8"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
</div>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

**C# Code-Behind:**

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int value1=0, value2=0;

        foreach (Control c in myradiolist.Controls)
        {
            if (c is RadioButtonList)
            {
                RadioButtonList rbl = (RadioButtonList)c;

                if(rbl.SelectedValue.Equals("1"))
                    value1++;

                if (rbl.SelectedValue.Equals("2"))
                    value2++; 
            }
        }           
    }
```

Comment: +1, except you might want to edit the code again to set the `Value` in each control to either a 1 or a 2.

Comment: @jp2code, but the OP does not require that in his post? Or am I missing something? :)

Comment: In `RadioButtonList4`, for example, you would not have a way to add a value to **value1** or **value2**, because your `asp:ListItems` contain only `Value="7"` and `Value="8"`.  ...or I am missing something! :)

Comment: @jp2code, you are correct, thats true. But you should ask OP that question becuase I used his exact RadioLists, he might have missed something?